# @UniqueConstraint for more than two columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, constraints

In my Spring/hibernate project I'm using `uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"ID_A", "ID_B"})}` to validate a unique combination of columns in a table. This works fine when I only have two columns.

However when I want to add a third column `ID_C` to the constraint it no longer works.

1. Does `@UniqueConstraint` only allow for two columns?
2. If yes, then how would I validate the unique combination for more than two columns?

Thank you for the help,
/D

**Edit:** What I mean by "it no longer works" is that no exception is thrown when I add a new entry to the table. With two columns it throws an `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens?

Comment: If you look on the database table, do you see a constraint created?  Does it have 3 columns or less than three columns created?

Comment: Could you please provide further details? Like the dto/mapping class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) alone to entity does not perform any validation. As said in the linked documentation, it gives instructions that are used in database schema generation:

> Specifies that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated
>   DDL for a primary or secondary table.

Now you have two options left:

1. Let Hibernate to generate database schema
2. Drop old constraint and add new by using SQL as usually.

Comment: I was already having hibernate generate the database schema but your second option got me thinking. I had a mysqldump that I was loading data from and it did not contain the new constraint which meant it dropped the tables hibernate created and recreated the old ones without the constraints. Also, thanks for the clarification on UniqueConstraint. /D